# Display slideshow on Android from files on PC

Tags: gallery

Ok, this has me frustrated. The good slideshow/gallery apps are already few and far between. But the wanted feature of having the Android show pictures that are stored on my PC, leaves the number of apps to, zero, it seems. I just can't find anything that works.

What I do is I run ushare on my Linux box. A couple of upnp browser apps confirm that they're seeing the ushare, and I can see the files being advertised. Then next, is any gallery app, that can actually access that available content and put on a slideshow.

My Android box is an Android TV box in the living hooked up to the large TV.

If I get fed up, I'll have to slap something together myself. I might concoct a network protocol myself, to give me good control over being able to only transfer what's need to show content...
Any thoughts?

Comment: ... I'm absolutely flabbergasted at the low quality of the slideshow apps in general. There are a few "ok" ones, but it's all pretty poor in features, and most are very confusing and lacking features. It seems like a huge hole in the market to me. Wouldn't this be something that many people might want? People have big tvs, and Android sticks or boxes turning their tv into a smart tv? Plus a PC in the house with a all the picture content? So, how does one display a slideshow on that tv? I can't be the only one that thought of doing this? Weird!